# How does JavaFX works with X11?

Tags: java, linux, javafx, x11

I try to understand how javafx works with x11. For now I think it works this way:

```
JavaFx application -> JavaFx API -> C implementation working with X11-> X11 ->Screen.
```

Am I right? By other words is there any dependance on Qt or GTK?

Comment: From the [Oracle certified configuration document for Java 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/certconfig-2095354.html): "For Linux platforms, gtk2 2.18+ is required for supporting JavaFX.".  You can also find documentation you can read on [the JavaFX architecture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/jfx-architecture.htm) and the [JavaFX source](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Main).